# How to force single value terra::rast to plot as continuous

Tags: r, terra

I have a couple of raster in R. Some have a range of values while others have a single value (all 0, for instance). I want to plot all rasters with the same color scale and legend so I can visually compare them. I'm using `terra::plot` parameters *type* and *range* to control this. But for some reason, the rasters that have a single value will not use the *type* and *range* setting.

Is it possible to have a raster with only one value plot as continuous and manually setting its scale?

Here goes a reprex:

```r
# Force a raster with a single value to plot as continuous

library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

r1 <- matrix(sin(1:100), ncol = 10, nrow = 10) |>
  rast()
minmax(r1)
#>           lyr.1
#> [1,] -0.9999902
#> [2,]  0.9999119
# I can change the scale with range, even though data is from -1 to 1
plot(r1, type = 'continuous', range = c(-2, 2))
```

[image]

```r
# if raster has one value, I can't plot as continuous or set range
r2 <- matrix(1, ncol = 10, nrow = 10) |>
  rast()
minmax(r2)
#>      lyr.1
#> [1,]     1
#> [2,]     1
plot(r2, type = 'continuous', range = c(-2, 2))
```

[image]

```r
plot(c(r1,r2), type = 'continuous', range = c(-2,2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'd consider this to be a bug and file an issue at [rspatial/terra](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues).